# dpan does not find Perl module in package root

Tags: perl, module, dpan

We use [MyCPAN::App::DPAN](http://p3rl.org/MyCPAN::App::DPAN) (Version 1.28) just like in Question: [How can I manage Perl module dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213217/how-can-i-manage-perl-module-dependencies)

This works quite well in general. But we ran into troubles with some specific packages:
As expample [DBD::Oracle](http://p3rl.org/DBD::Oracle) does not have their main `*.pm` file in `DBD-Oracle-1.27/lib/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.pm` but in `DBD-Oracle-1.27/Oracle.pm`.

It seems that `dpan` does not find this `*.pm` file, since it is not listed in `modules/02packages.details.txt.gz`. Whereas `DBD::Oracle::Object` (other Perl-Module of this distribution, but located `DBD-Oracle-1.27/lib/DBD/Oracle/`) is listed there.

In `dpan.conf` we only have set the recommended values:

```
dpan_dir   /some/dir
indexer_id   Me 
pause_full_name   The Admin Team
pause_id   TAT
system_id   my system id
```

Other Packages with the same problem:

- [Apache::DB](http://p3rl.org/Apache::DB)

Packages that work:

- [Crypt::Blowfish](http://p3rl.org/Crypt::Blowfish) (no extra modules)
- [Math::Round](http://p3rl.org/Math::Round) (no extra modules)
- [XML::Twig](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig) (no "lib" dir, but extra modules)

Does someone have any tips/hints?

Comment: You could file a bug report on [RT](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=MyCPAN-App-DPAN).

Comment: I'll look at these two distros and get back to you. The trick with the DPAN stuff is guessing all the weird stuff that distribution authors do. You might also try the stuff in github, which may have already fixed this.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: Thanks for the RT-tip. I thought of this option too, but brian d foy's activity here at stackoverflow seems to be way higher. So I posted here at stackoverflow. But I must admit, it is not the top correct way.

Comment: @brian d foy: Thanks for your great work! Having looked a few distribution packages, I can understand that scanning all of those is very difficult job.

Comment: Well, my activity at RT is much higher, and if there's something there, I'll see the report when I come back to do more work. I won't remember that there's something on Stackoverflow. You should always use the issue tracking tool, even if in addition to a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPAN works by indexing the distributions and storing the results in a file in the indexer_reports directory. As a workaround until I can investigate your problem, you can just edit the report it created for the problem distributions. As long as you haven't set `fresh_start` in your configuration, it will use the cached report which you have edited to add the missing module.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I read about the option: `extra_reports` in the pod files. But I did not know what to write in those or where I could find them. I'll try it on mondays back at work!

Comment: I managed to work around the indexing problem, using manually created extra reports. Thank you for the tip!